# Make a cache system for Express JS app connect with API

Tags: node.js, api, express, caching

[level english = very bad (from France...)]

I have a simple app with node.js and epress.js

This app use de module "igdb-api-node" for connecting with the igdb api (https://www.igdb.com/api)

I use this code for get a game whith keyword :

```js
exports.findGameByKeyWord = function(req, res) {
  return client.games({
      fields: '*',
      limit: 20,
      offset: 0,
      search: req.params.text
  }).then(igdbResponse => {
    res.send(igdbResponse.body);
  });
};
```

All this work great, but now I would like to store the result of my request in cache.

I want make this for speed up the return of result.

I have watching differents ideas for make that but this is little complicated for me, I would like an exemple to understand.

Here, the tracks that I explored :

https://github.com/BryanDonovan/node-cache-manager

https://www.npmjs.com/package/route-cache

https://github.com/kwhitley/apicache

https://github.com/evanshortiss/express-expeditious

https://github.com/dantman/express-cache-response-directive

Comment: Please have a look at https://glitch.com/edit/#!/server-side-cache-express?path=server.js:9:0

Comment: I just tested this solution, I didn't have an error message, but the loading time has not been shortened, how to know that the application has retrieve the information in the cache rather than in the api?